# install the text editor ckeditor with grocery crud

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckeditor, grocery-crud

I want to install ckeditor with grocery crud. Can anyone please tell me how to install it in grocery CRUD. Please help :(

The current website text editor is TinyMCE but the problem with it that it has no image upload

Comment: CKeditor and Grocery CRUD have nothing in common. What do you mean by `install the text editor ckeditor with grocery crud`?

Comment: I want to add CKeditor as a text editor in a grocery crud application

Answer (score 0):

You can configure what editor to use in the file application/config/grocery_crud.php

```
//You can choose 'ckeditor','tinymce' or 'markitup'
$config['grocery_crud_default_text_editor'] = 'ckeditor';
```